# Variable Undefined after jQuery Change

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps-api-3

```
var circle = new google.maps.Circle({
    center: latLng,
    radius: radius,
    strokeColor: "#FF0000",
    strokeOpacity: 0.5,
    strokeWeight: 1,
    fillColor: "#FF0000",
    fillOpacity: 0.2
});

circle.setMap(map);

map.fitBounds(circle.getBounds());

jQuery('#area').change(function() {
    radius = jQuery('#area').val();

    var newLatLng = marker.getPosition();

    circle.setMap(null);

    var circle = new google.maps.Circle({
        center: latLng,
        radius: radius,
        strokeColor: "#FF0000",
        strokeOpacity: 0.5,
        strokeWeight: 1,
        fillColor: "#FF0000",
        fillOpacity: 0.2
    });

    circle.setMap(map);

    map.fitBounds(circle.getBounds());
});
```

`circle` is defined outside the `jQuery('#area').change()` but when I try to access it from inside the `jQuery('#area').change()` function, I get an undefined error. Why is this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside your .change function, change this line:

```
var circle = new google.maps.Circle({
```

to this:

```
circle = new google.maps.Circle({
```

The way you had it, you were creating a new local variable named `circle` and setting it's value and you were not setting the value of the global defintion of `circle`.  Then, when you come in the next time and call `circle.setMap(null)` on the global one, it's still null.

So, if you only mean to be operating on the global definition of circle, then remove the `var` as above in the `.change()` function.  If you meant to create a new temporary circle object for use only during that `.change()` function that would not survive past the execution of that function, then name that local copy something other than `circle`.

Answer (score 3):

Because your inner function contains `var circle`.  Due to a phenomenon known as "var hoisting", the entire function considers `circle` to be a local variable, even though the var statement appears later.

Name your inner function's circle something else.

Comment: Agree with jimbojw here is a fiddle that demonstrates: http://jsfiddle.net/Pks4R/

Comment: +1 Great answer. All variable declarations within a scope are treated by the interpreter as the first line in that scope.